# Are Bluetooth device names case-sensitive?

Tags: linux, windows-10, bluetooth, ios

I have both a Windows 10 Bluetooth device named `MY-DEVICE` and a Linux (kernel version 4.15) Bluetooth device named `my-device`. Will they be identified as different devices on my iPhone running iOS 11?

Comment: What is your OS? Your question is unanswerable without that information.

Comment: @DavidPostill Thank you for your advice. I have edited the question.